# Using multiple M2M relationship across multiple database in peewee

Tags: python, database, orm, peewee

I have two python projects which maintain their different database connections and sqlite files. `model1.py` is in the low-level project, `model2.py` is in the high-level project which using the model class of `model1.py`. The following is the sample code:

model1.py

```py
from os.path import join, dirname

from peewee import *
from playhouse.sqlite_ext import *

_db = SqliteDatabase(join(dirname(__file__), 'db1.sqlite'))

class Student(Model):
    name = CharField()
    sex = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = _db

    def __str__(self):
        return 'student name: %s, sex: %s' % (self.name, self.sex)

_db.connect()
_db.create_tables([
    Student,
])
```

model2.py

```py
from os.path import join, dirname

from peewee import *
from playhouse.sqlite_ext import *

from model1 import *

_db = SqliteDatabase(join(dirname(__file__), 'db2.sqlite'))

class Teacher(Model):
    name = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()

    sample_student = ForeignKeyField(Student, null=True, backref='sample_teacher')
    students = ManyToManyField(Student, backref='teachers')

    class Meta:
        database = _db

    def __str__(self):
        return 'teacher name: %s, age: %d' % (self.name, self.age)

_db.connect()
_db.create_tables([
    Teacher,
    Teacher.students.get_through_model(),
])
```

main.py

```py
from model1 import *
from model2 import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Teacher.students.through_model.delete().execute()
    Teacher.delete().execute()
    Student.delete().execute()

    s1 = Student.create(name='s1', sex='male')
    s2 = Student.create(name='s2', sex='female')

    t1 = Teacher.create(name='t1', age=20)
    t1.students.add(s1)
    t1.students.add(s2)

    t1.sample_student = s1
    t1.save()

    print(t1.sample_student)  # ForeignKeyField works!

    [print(s) for s in Student.select()]
    [print(t) for t in Teacher.select()]

    for s in t1.students:    # crash here: peewee.OperationalError: no such table: teacher_student_through
        print(s)
```

For the table `teacher_student_through`, it exists in `db2.sqlite` database actually. So, is this a bug of `peewee` or wrong usage of mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the database object for `Meta.database`, I redesigned the meta model initialization with **database proxy** for my python package.

```py
_db_proxy = DatabaseProxy()

class PeeweeModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = _db_proxy

# skip the other subclass models implementation here...

def setup_database(dbpath):
    '''Initialize database.'''

    database = SqliteDatabase(dbpath)
    _db_proxy.initialize(database)

    database.connect(reuse_if_open=True)
    database.create_tables([
        Model1,
        Model2,
    ])

    return database
```

The package caller now has the responsibility to initialize the database object, [see more documentation about this](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration).

The public `PeeweeModel` is also available for the high-level python package to extend the database tables, just use it as a common super model class.